# JQUERYMobile Site Showing Up Wide like PC version

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I switched my jquery includes to the latest versions and now my site is showing up all wide like a PC site on both android and iphone.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
```

Current Head

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title></title>

<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>

    </head>
```

Any ideas?

SOLUTION

I added `<meta content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1" name="viewport">.`and its fine now.

Comment: Your solution is indeed correct; the latest version of jQM removed the default viewport setting found in the alphas. Why not add your solution as an answer and accept it? You can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better viewport value :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi">
```

Comment: I tried your line but it makes everything a little bit zoomed out on Android Xperia.  I took out  target-densityDpi=device-dpi and it shows up normal now.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION

I added .and its fine now.

```
<meta content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1" name="viewport">
```